# MBProcessHUD show/hide when using semaphore

Tags: ios, multithreading, block, semaphore, mbprogresshud

Hi I m using dispatch_group_t for async web call and during that wait period I want to show activity indicator.
Here is my code which is not working for show/hide activity indicator.

```
- (BaseResponse*)getResponse:(BaseRequest*)request{

    request.header = [[Header alloc]init];
    request.header.osType = 2;       

    NSString *jsonBody = [request toJSONString];

    NSURL *requestURL = @"myurl";

    __block BaseResponse *baseResponse;

    [self showHUDProcessView];  //here activity indicator should start animating but not working as per expected.

    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
    dispatch_group_enter(group);

    [[COMHandler sharedCOMHandler] makeServiceCall:jsonBody requestURL_:requestURL completion:^(ComResponse *comResponse){

        [self hideHUDProcessView]; //hide  activity when receive response

        if (comResponse != nil) {
            baseResponse = comResponse;
        }else{             
           //show alert
        }         
        dispatch_group_leave(group);                       
    }];             
   dispatch_group_wait(group,  DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
   return baseResponse;
}
- (void) showHUDProcessView {     
     [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:viewController.view animated:YES];       
}

- (void) hideHUDProcessView {
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
              dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{                
                [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:viewController.view animated:YES];   

        });
    });
}
```

I also tried with starting group in block but also not work..
Tried

```
dispatch_semaphore_t activity =  dispatch_semaphore_create(0); 
       //show indicator
       ^myblock {
          //hide indicator
          dispatch_semaphore_signal(activity);
        }
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(activity, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

also but no luck.
Can anybody suggest me when i m doing wrong??
Or want else I can do to achieve this indicator show/hide issue.

Comment: Don't use group wait or semaphore. Those are blocking the main thread and will interfere with your hud. It will be the source of other problems, too. Don't try to return a value from `getResponse`, but instead change the return type to `void` and them supply a completion handler block parameter.

Comment: Hi @Rob exactly same thing i did before, that my method return type was void and returning response with completion handler but as per my design getResponse is called from individual web service class like one of the case LoginRequest class call getResponse. So there are many other Request class from where i want to call getResponse method ,if i do so as you suggested then have to redefine all  Request methods prototype.

Comment: You really should revert `getResponse` back to its asynchronous, completion handler pattern. And any routines that call it should, themselves, adopt asynchronous patterns, too. It might feel daunting right now, but I suspect that once you dive into it, you'll be able to knock it out in no time. This synchronous pattern that you have here has deeper problems, so it's not just the HUD. You really want to embrace the asynchronous patterns.

Comment: @Rob thanks for your feedback..it really helped